# difference between instruction level parallelism and parallel processing

Tags: process, architecture, processor

I do not understand the difference between instruction level parallelism and parallel processing. please help. it would be helpful if anyone gives some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ILP

1 . Overlap individual machine operations 
(add, mul, load…) so that they execute
 in parallel

2 . Transparent to the user

3 . Goal: speed up execution

## Parallel Processing

1. Having separate processors getting separate chunks of the program ( processors programmed to do so)
2. Nontransparent to the user
3. Goal: speed up and quality up